# Removing duplicate posts from WordPress REST API using wp_remote_get

Tags: wordpress, multidimensional-array, wordpress-rest-api, multisite

I'm working with WordPress multisite where the top level site shows posts from all of the microsites.  The problem is, while some of these microsites have unique posts, some of them have "duplicate" posts.  On the top level site, I'm using `wp_remote_get` to fetch the posts of the microsites but I need a way to filter out the duplicates (probably by search for duplicate titles.

I've tried searching on Stack Overflow and thought `array_unique` would help but I don't think it will because it's a multi-dimensional array containing objects with post data.

Here is my code and what I tried.  Showing the loop as well in case it helps:

```
<?php
$head_text = carbon_get_the_post_meta( 'crb_events_head_text' );

$request = wp_remote_get("https://example.com/wp-json/app/v1/get-events/");
$events  = $request ? json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request ) ) : '';

$per_page = 12;

$events = array_unique($events,SORT_REGULAR);

$paged    = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$offset   = $paged == 1 ? 0 : ( ( $paged - 1 ) * $per_page );
$total    = count( $events );

$events   = array_slice( $events, $offset, $per_page );

if ( ! $events ) {
    $head_text = '<h1>' . __( 'There currently aren\'t any events scheduled.<br /> Please check back soon.', 'crb' ) . '</h1>';
}

?>

<section class="section-articles section-articles--events">
    <div class="shell">
        <?php if ( ! empty( $head_text ) ) : ?>
            <header class="section__head">
                <div class="shell">
                    <?php echo crb_content( $head_text ); ?>
                </div><!-- /.shell -->
            </header><!-- /.section__head -->
        <?php endif ?>

        <div class="section__inner">
            <?php if ( $events ) : ?>
                <ol class="articles-blog slick-slides">
                    <?php foreach ( $events as $event ) : ?>
                        <li class="article">
                            <div class="article__wrap">
                                <?php if ( $event->thumbnail ) : ?>
                                    <div class="article__image-wrap">
                                        <a href="<?php echo ! empty( $event->link_url ) ? esc_url( $event->link_url ) : $event->permalink; ?>" target="<?php echo ! empty( $event->link_url ) ? '_blank' : '_self'; ?>" class="article__image">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $event->thumbnail; ?>" alt="">
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.article__image-wrap -->
                                <?php endif ?>

                                <div class="article__inner">
                                    <div class="article__head">
                                        <div class="article__meta">
                                            <p>
                                                <strong><?php echo $event->dates; ?></strong>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>

                                        <h2 class="article__title">
                                            <a href="<?php echo ! empty( $event->link_url ) ? esc_url( $event->link_url ) : $event->permalink; ?>" target="<?php echo ! empty( $event->link_url ) ? '_blank' : '_self'; ?>"><?php echo $event->title; ?></a>
                                        </h2><!-- /.article__title -->
                                    </div><!-- /.article__head -->

                                    <div class="article__aside">
                                        <?php if ( ! empty( $event->desc ) ) : ?>
                                            <div class="article__entry">
                                                <?php echo wpautop( $event->desc ); ?>
                                            </div><!-- /.article__entry -->
                                        <?php endif ?>

                                        <?php if ( ( ! empty( $event->link_url ) || ! empty( $event->permalink ) ) && ! empty( $event->link_label ) ) : ?>
                                            <div class="article__actions">
                                                <a href="<?php echo ! empty( $event->link_url ) ? esc_url( $event->link_url ) : $event->permalink; ?>" target="<?php echo ! empty( $event->link_url ) ? '_blank' : '_self'; ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $event->link_label ); ?></a>
                                            </div><!-- /.article__actions -->
                                        <?php endif ?>
                                    </div><!-- /.article__aside -->
                                </div><!-- /.article__inner -->
                            </div><!-- /.article__wrap -->
                        </li><!-- /.article -->
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol><!-- /.articles -->

            <?php endif ?>
        </div><!-- /.section__inner -->
    </div><!-- /.shell -->
</section>
```

Here is an example of what it looks like when I print the $events variable so you can see the structure (and possibly see my issue where it shows some duplicates because the microsite has a different site ID.
[image]